# How to load two mysql tables instead of one (opencrypt)?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using "AJAX data listings engine with PHP and mySQL (BETA)" from OC

http://www.opencrypt.com/blog.php?a=22

And having trouble understanding how to load two tables data?

```
require "data_engine.php";
$output = data_engine_select("sales_flat_quote", "reserved_order_id|customer_email|customer_firstname|customer_lastname|store_id|quote_currency_code|subtotal|entity_id", "1", "50|1", "reserved_order_id|desc", "", "", "", "", "");
```

This is my code, I don't know where to insert data so it loads

```
where sales_flat_quote.entity_id=sales_flat_order_item.quote_item_id
```

and picks SKU cell from sales_flat_order_item that matches quote_item_id from entity_id and displays into another column

function data_engine_select($conf_table, $conf_columns, $conf_headers = "1", $conf_rows = "", $conf_order = "", $conf_edit = "0", $conf_query = "", $conf_header = "", $conf_footer = "", $conf_buttons = "") {

```
# table: mySQL table name
# columns: field names/mySQL colum names to display (in table), seperate with pipe delimeter, field1|field2|field4
# headers: 0 = no column names displayed, 1 = column names are displayed
# rows to display: number of rows to return, and whether to enable pages.  e.g. 20, would list 20 results.  20|1 would list 20 + other pages.  blank or 0/default is all results, and no pages (max 999999 results).
# default order = order of results, field by desc/asc.  e.g. FIELDNAME|DESC
# edit = position|type, type 0 = no, 1 = radio, 2 = checkbox. position 0 = default, on left, 1 = on right
# query = custom mySQL query.  after the WHERE.  e.g. FIELDNAME = 'keyword', the WHERE is inserted automatically, incase an AND is required
# header = places input (html or text) after header names
# footer = places input (html or text) after rows, before page links.
# button = places input (html or text) in bottom left, instead of 'Page 1 of 2' text.
```